# How to change colors of VC++ project window

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, colors, themes

I have a project done in visual studio 2010 vc++
i have multiple windows created at runtime using WNDCLASS. I want to create a color themes that apply to all the windows on creation.

1. Is there a way that i can change defaul window color constant to desired color? e.g. if  change value of COLOR_BTNFACE, it will update all the refereed window buttons automatically.
2. Is there any other method to implement the custom theme to my project without having to manually search and replace used colors.??

thanks in advance
regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing the background color of all your windows at runtime because of applying another theme needs some implementation effort from your side. As afar as I know there is no mechanism that can do this for you.

Assuming you have an Windows application written and you want to have theming support at runtime:

What I would not do:
You can create your own window classes (WNDCLASS) and set an background color (HBRUSH hbrBackground) you like and create all your windows from this window classes. This has some severe drawbacks since you need to create a window class for each class of windows (Buttuns, Sliders, Popup windows, ...) and you can not change this at runtime without recreating all the windows.

What I would do:
I would introduce a common base class for all windows my application creates. That base class contains such things a the background color (among other common useful things). When applying another background color you just need to tell all your windows about that change (via a setBackgroundColor()) so they can repaint there content.

I hope that helps.

Comment: let me clarify please. the colors are to be changed while creating all the windows. no color change required once all windows are created. can you please provide an example for both your suggestions?? my app consists of list box, text box and buttons apart of labels and text etc.